# invalid explicit template argument(s) xmemory()

Tags: c++, memory-management

The aforementioned error (C2770) has poped up for xmemory() file along with others like 
Error   C2825   '_Ty': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'. I have found some questions here and there about such error but none regarding xmemory() especially that I can't edit it...

The error arise from the declaration of the struct below (Variable). The issue is with the enum (s) CompositionMaterials and EquipmentSpecs which are declared as follows (respectively)

```
enum EquipmentSpecs{
    LNGColdOutletTemp=1,
    LNGHotOutletTemp=2,
};
//If you ever added any new compositions below, make sure to register them also in HYSYSCompositionsMap with their equivalent HYSYS names
enum CompositionMaterials{
    Nitrogen=1,
    Methane=2,
    Ethane=3,
    Propane=4,
    iButane=5,
    nButane=6,
    Water=7,
};
enum DecisionVariable{
MolFlow=1,
Pressure=2,
Temperature=3,
Composition=4,
EquipmentSpec=5,
};
struct Variable{
string StreamOREquipmentName; 
DecisionVariable TypeOfVar;
double MaxBound;
double MinBound;
CompositionMaterials Constituent; //IF TypeOfVar is Composition
EquipmentSpecs Spec; //IF TypeOfVar is EquipmentSpec
double BaseValue; //Used to reset the case in case of a problem occured in last runs
};
vector<Variable> DecVar;
```

The error is reported in the following few lines of xmemory() file:

```
        // TEMPLATE STRUCT _Get_rebind_type
template<class _Ty,
    class _Other>
    struct _Get_rebind_type
    _GET_TYPE_OR_DEFAULT(template rebind<_Other>::other,
        typename _Replace_first_parameter<_Other _COMMA _Uty>::type);
```

The following part is where the aforementioned variables are used

```
else if( (DecVar[ ii ].TypeOfVar == EquipmentSpec) && (DecVar[ ii ].Spec == LNGColdOutletTemp) ){

            //This means that the variable is outlet cold temperature of LNG operation, u loop through equipment and set outlet temperature of hot streams to this particular value { gene(i) }
            for( j = 0; j < OperationsCount; j++ ){
                _variant_t t = _variant_t( j );
                Connection.GetOperation( t );
                IDispatch* hyOp = Connection.hyOperation;
                string name = Connection.GetName( hyOp );
                if( name == DecVar[ ii ].StreamOREquipmentName ){
                    int Feeds = Connection.GetOperationFeedCount( hyOp );
                    int Products = Connection.GetOperationProductCount( hyOp );
                    if( Feeds != Products ){
                        cout << "Discrepency between feed count and product count of an LNG, error in source 1603" << endl;
                        return OOPS;
                    }
                    for( int C = 0; C < Feeds; C++ ){
                        IDispatch* ThisIndexFeedStrm;
                        IDispatch* ThisIndexProductStrm;
                        ThisIndexFeedStrm = Connection.GetOperationFeedStream( _variant_t( C ) );
                        ThisIndexProductStrm = Connection.GetOperationProductStream( _variant_t( C ) );
                        double FeedTemp = Connection.GetTemperature( ThisIndexFeedStrm );
                        double ProductTemp = Connection.GetTemperature( ThisIndexProductStrm );
                        if( ( FeedTemp == ProductTemp ) || ( FeedTemp == NAN ) || ( ProductTemp == NAN ) ) {
                            cout << "You got a useless LNG operation, error in source 1656" << endl;
                        }
                        else if( FeedTemp < ProductTemp ){
                            //This means it is a cold stream
                            Connection.SetTemperature( ThisIndexProductStrm, genome1.gene( ii ) );

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: In c++ there can be multiple error messages for each your mistake. Post *all* errors until you encounter the one that is located in *your* source  code.

Comment: @RustyX Thanks for your comment. The point is that there is none in my source code other than some harmless warnings like (conversion from float to double, loss of data which is cool by me since earlier versions) All the errors (not warnings) are denoted to xmemory() file

Comment: But here are they anyway

Error C2770 invalid explicit template argument(s) for 'std::_Identity<_Replace_first_parameter<_Other,_Uty>::type> std::_Get_rebind_type<_Alloc,_Other>::_Fn(std::_Wrap_int)' 

Error C2825 '_Ty': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::' 
Error C2510 '_Ty': left of '::' must be a class/struct/union 

Error C2146 syntax error: missing '>' before identifier 'value_type' 
Error C2893 Failed to specialize function template 'std::_Identity<ptrdiff_t> std::_Get_pointer_type<_Alloc>::_Fn(std::_Wrap_int)'

Comment: Error C4430 missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int 
Error C3646 'value_type': unknown override specifier

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake, I'm going to edit the code now. I think I have pinpointed the error location